# MySQL 5.7.x: password expiry set, user table column `password_expired` shows "N" when password is expired. Why?

Tags: mysql-5.7

This seems like a bug, but I can't find any reports of this anywhere and given the age of this server, I'm curious if I'm just misunderstanding the purpose of this flag.

The following example (real) table:

```
mysql> select user, host, password_last_changed, password_expired, password_lifetime from user;
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| user             | host      | password_last_changed | password_expired | password_lifetime |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+
| usera            | %         | 2022-11-07 16:08:58   | N                |                 2 |
| testuser         | %         | 2022-08-15 16:01:18   | N                |                 2 |
| mysql.infoschema | localhost | 2022-07-08 11:19:51   | N                |              NULL |
| mysql.session    | localhost | 2022-07-08 11:19:51   | N                |              NULL |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | 2022-07-08 11:19:51   | N                |              NULL |
| root             | localhost | 2022-09-05 18:24:17   | N                |              NULL |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+------------------+-------------------+
```

A couple of things to note. The default (i.e. global) password expiry is set for two days. Each non-root and non-system user is also set for a 2 day expiry.

When I logged in as `usera`, I was presented, correctly, with the requirement to update my password.

Now as root, I am checking the users and I saw the aforementioned table. Clearly, `testuser` is expired. Why is `password_expired` "N"? Is this normal or a bug? Also before I get the "hater" comments to upgrade to v8.x, we can't...yet. We're stuck on 5.7 for now, but we are using the latest patch level of 5.7.x.

Comment: *Why is password_expired "N"?* In general the columns `password_last_changed`+`password_lifetime` values set is enough for to define does the password lifetime is expired. I.e. this is "automated way". `password_expired` column provides "by-hand way", it allows the DBA to expire the password regardless the values in two above columns (using according ALTER USER statement) - for example when the password is compromised.

Comment: Oh, hmm. OK, so if I'm understanding you correctly; the `password_expired` column is not meant to be used by the system to flag a password expired. Rather, it's used by the DBA to manually expire a password. Is that accurate? Do you have a link to documentation for that? Also, feel free to make this the answer and I'll accept it as such.